# Using regex to match the last math operator in a given string calculation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to use regex to match the last mathematical operator in a calculation string.

For example, In the string:

"25+4-1*100/423", it will match '/'

Or

"25*2*4444*123+4", it will match '+'

I have tried the regex `/(\-|\+|\/|\*)(?=[^\-\+\/\*]*$)/`, but for some reason it matches twice the last operator twice.

For example:

```
var str = "25+4-1*3" 
var regex = /(\-|\+|\/|\*)(?=[^\-\+\/\*]*$)/
str.match(regex) = ["*", "*"]
```

Comment: Your regex [matches the last operator](https://regex101.com/r/vMvv6u/1).

Comment: What makes you think it matches it twice?

Comment: `var str = "25+4-1*3"` when I type `str.match(regex)` I get `["*", "*"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *regex* works absolute fine. You just need to add a global (`g`) flag when matching the string.

```js
var str = "25+4-1*3";
var result = str.match(/(\-|\+|\/|\*)(?=[^\-\+\/\*]*$)/g);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Adding a `g` just hides the real problem, which is the capture group. It does work with `match`; with `exec` it could be an issue.

Comment: By capture group I'm guessing you mean `(\-|\+|\/|\*)`? What is wrong with it?

Comment: @JosephLiu: As I said in my answer (and a comment), it's why you're getting two entries in the array from `match`. Adding a `g` flag is a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: also, could be done with a char. class `[+\-*\/]`, w/o the `g` flag

Answer (score 0):

> but for some reason it matches twice the last operator twice.
>
> `var str = "25+4-1*3"` when I type `str.match(regex)` I get `["*", "*"]`

`RegExp#exec` and `String#match` both return an array of results with the *overall* match (for the whole expression) as the first entry and then the values of any capture groups as subsequent entries. Since you have a capture group, that means you see the operator in both the first and second positions.

Just remove the capture group (make it a non-capturing group), as the whole expression other than the lookahead is the capture group:

```js
var regex = /(?:\-|\+|\/|\*)(?=[^\-\+\/\*]*$)/;
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- non-capturing group
var str = "25+4-1*3"
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

If for some reason you needed the capture group (e.g., if there were more to the expression than just the lookahead), you'd keep it but then just ignore the first entry in the array (if you only wanted the capture).

Comment: Thanks for explaining it in detail, but it still doesn't make sense to me! Sorry regex is completely foreign to me!!

Comment: @JosephLiu: Suppose we had `/[a-z]{3}([a-z]{3})/`, which is an expression saying "match any six characters a-z and put the last three into a capture group." If you do `"123foobar456".match(/[a-z]{3}([a-z]{3})/)` you'll see `["foobar", "bar"]`: The first entry is what matched the *whole expression* (`"foobar"`); the second entry is what matched only the *capture group* (`"bar"`). In your original regex, all of the matching (non-lookahead) parts were in the capture group, so you saw the same thing for the first and second entries in the array.

Comment: So the curved brackets `()` makes it a capture group?

Comment: @JosephLiu: `(something)` defines a capturing group, yes. `(?:something)` defines a *non-capturing* group (we need it above for the lookahead to work).

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining :)